# Grails - How can I get serverURL in config.groovy?

Tags: grails

I want to use ServerURL in `config.groovy`.

But, I need configure `url.setting` both development and production if I cannot use `serverURL` in `config.groovy`.

I try to get `serverURL` like below, it makes error.

config.groovy

```
def grailsApplication
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080"
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.serverURL = "http://myapp.com"
    }
}
url.setting = "${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}"
```

the error when I run app is like below

```
Error Error packaging application: Error loading Config.groovy: Cannot get property 'config' on null object (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: try `"${grails.config.grails.serverURL}"`

Comment: It does not make a error, but it return null, `[:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the server URL like-

```
url.setting="${grails.serverURL}"
```